# Liferay portal-ext LDAP configuration

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, liferay, liferay-6

For the first time i configured the LDAP connection i did it through the Liferay control panel and everything worked just fine. But now i want to configure it through portal-ext.properties file, these are my configurations:

```
ldap.auth.enabled=true
ldap.import.enabled=true
ldap.import.on.startup=true
ldap.import.method=user
ldap.auth.required=true
ldap.export.enabled=false

ldap.base.provider.url=ldap://********************
ldap.base.dn=********************
ldap.security.principal=********************
ldap.security.credentials=********************

ldap.user.mappings.0=uuid=\nscreenName=sAMAccountName\npassword=userPassword\nemailAddress=mail\nfirstName=givenName\nlastName=sN\njobTitle=\ngroup=memberOf\n
ldap.auth.search.filter.0=(sAMAccountName=@screen_name@)

ldap.import.user.search.filter.0=(objectClass=person)
ldap.import.group.search.filter.0=(objectClass=group)
ldap.group.mappings.0=groupName=cn\ndescription=description\nuser=uniqueMember
ldap.user.custom.mappings.0=
ldap.contact.mappings.0=
ldap.contact.custom.mappings.0=
```

Besides this, everytime i change some configuration i clean the database just to be sure that the file is properly read.

When i run the server and go to the LDAP authentication in the control panel all the configurations are exactly as i configured in the portal-ext file (even the Test LDAP Connection is working fine) but the Users configurations are empty. Can you explain why i'm having this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem! I just removed the server id from all configurations and now the fields in control panel are finally filled.

These are the correct ldap configurations:

```
ldap.auth.enabled=true
ldap.import.enabled=true
ldap.import.on.startup=true
ldap.import.method=user
ldap.auth.required=true
ldap.export.enabled=false

ldap.base.provider.url=ldap://********************
ldap.base.dn=********************
ldap.security.principal=********************
ldap.security.credentials=********************

ldap.user.mappings=uuid=\nscreenName=sAMAccountName\npassword=userPassword\nemailAddress=mail\nfirstName=givenName\nlastName=sN\njobTitle=\ngroup=memberOf\n
ldap.auth.search.filter=(sAMAccountName=@screen_name@)

ldap.import.user.search.filter=(objectClass=person)
ldap.import.group.search.filter=(objectClass=group)
ldap.group.mappings=groupName=cn\ndescription=description\nuser=uniqueMember
ldap.user.custom.mappings=
ldap.contact.mappings=
ldap.contact.custom.mappings=
```

Another way to make it work is to add the server id in the connection configurations just like this:

```
ldap.auth.enabled=true
ldap.import.enabled=true
ldap.import.on.startup=true
ldap.import.method=user
ldap.auth.required=true
ldap.export.enabled=false

ldap.base.provider.url.0=ldap://********************
ldap.base.dn.0=********************
ldap.security.principal.0=********************
ldap.security.credentials.0=********************

ldap.user.mappings.0=uuid=\nscreenName=sAMAccountName\npassword=userPassword\nemailAddress=mail\nfirstName=givenName\nlastName=sN\njobTitle=\ngroup=memberOf\n
ldap.auth.search.filter.0=(sAMAccountName=@screen_name@)

ldap.import.user.search.filter.0=(objectClass=person)
ldap.import.group.search.filter.0=(objectClass=group)
ldap.group.mappings.0=groupName=cn\ndescription=description\nuser=uniqueMember
ldap.user.custom.mappings.0=
ldap.contact.mappings.0=
ldap.contact.custom.mappings.0=
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to define following property to use id

```
ldap.server.ids=0
```

Also you need to use url, principal, credential and base.dn properties with id as follows same as others you used

```
ldap.base.provider.url.0=ldap://********************
ldap.base.dn.0=********************
ldap.security.principal.0=********************
ldap.security.credentials.0=********************
```

Hope this helps!